# ReactJS transferring props to dynamic component

Tags: reactjs

Currently I have built a very simple factory that looks at a JSON config and uses that to dynamically generate components and appropriate props for that component:

```
let exampleJSON = {
  "components": [
    {
      "type":"ComponentA",
      "params": { myProp: "hey there"  }
    },
    {
      "type":"ComponentB",
      "params": { myOtherProp: "Yo"  }
    }
  ]
}

const ComponentA = (props) => {
  let { myProp } = props;
  return  (
    <div>{ myProp }</div>
  )
}

const ComponentB = (props) => {
  let { myOtherProp } = props;
  return  (
    <div>{ myOtherProp }</div>
  )
}

const ComponentFactory = (props) => {
  const { content } = props;
  return (
    <div>
      { 
        content.components.map( (component, index) => {
          console.log(component);
          let Component = "" + component.type;
          return (
            <Component key={ index } {...component.params } />
          )
        })
       }
    </div>
  )
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <ComponentFactory content={ exampleJSON } />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Example at: http://codepen.io/jimhill/pen/LboGEY

However, whenever I run this I'm getting the error `Unknown prop`myProp`on <ComponentA> tag`. If I manually create it however I do not get this error.

Any ideas?

---

edit: this is fine if I define the elements in an object and reference them by key e.g.

```
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import ComponentA from './ComponentA';
import ComponentB from './ComponentB';

const components = {
    'ComponentA': ComponentA,
    'ComponentB': ComponentB
}

const TheFactory = (props) => {
    let Component = components[props.componentType];
    return (
        <div>
            <Component { ...props.componentProps } />
        <div>
    )
}

render(
    <TheFactory componentType="ComponentA" componentProps={ SomeProp:"An example" } />,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: That is weird. Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: Sure will enhance in a sec

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Is the below something similar to what you're trying to achieve?

```
const ComponentA = (props) => {
    let { myProp } = props;
    return  (
        <div>{ myProp }</div>
    )
}

const ComponentB = (props) => {
    let { myOtherProp } = props;
    return  (
        <div>{ myOtherProp }</div>
    )
}

let exampleJSON = {
    "components": [
        {
            "type": ComponentA,
            "params": { myProp: "hey there"  }
        },
        {
            "type": ComponentB,
            "params": { myOtherProp: "Yo..."  }
        }
    ]
}

const ComponentFactory = (props) => {
    const { content } = props;
    return (
        <div>
            { 
                content.components.map( (component, index) => {
                    let Component = component.type;
                    return (
                        <Component key={ index } {...component.params } />
                    )
                })
            }
        </div>
    )
};

ReactDOM.render(
    <ComponentFactory content={ exampleJSON } />,
document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: Although this still doesn't generate the component from a string name, it's the method that I chose too. Just defining the components and referencing them directly. Thanks @seisei :)